# Where to setup a UIView subclass' subviews?

Tags: ios, uiview, initialization, uilabel, drawrect

I have a simple `UIView` subclass where I place a `UILabel` within, in order to give such `UIView` a certain frame, background color and text format for its label from a `UIViewController`.

I'm reading the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW6) but there are some things that I'm not fully understanding... when your view has only system standard subviews, such my `UILabel`, should I override the `drawRect:` method? Or is that only intended for `Core Animation` staff? If I shouldn't setup standard subviews within such method, what is the correct place to do so? Should I then override the `init` method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not override the drawRect for initializing the sub views because it causes a performance hit. That should be done either in the init, initWithFrame, or initWithCoder methods. For example, this is how you do it using the initWithFrame method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
      //initialize sub views 
  }
  return self;
```

Comment: Note that the `UIView` implementation of `init` just calls `initWithFrame` with a `CGRectZero`. You should therefore always override `initWithFrame` (or `initWithCoder` if you're using NSCoding).

Comment: Thank you. Just another question came to me: what about setting the subviews by overriding the `layoutSubviews` method? Would that be more appropriate than setting them in the initialization method?

Comment: You should override `layoutSubviews` to perform any custom layout logic for your subviews, such as updating their frames. As it can be called multiple times during a `UIView`s lifetime, it's not appropriate for *initialising* the subviews themselves. This should be done in an initialiser.

Comment: @Hamish what if for initialising some subviews you need to have the actual frame of the view?